# Not able to retrive data from database in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new to django. I am trying to obtain data from a profile page that I've created which exists in a app called users and I am trying to use the data in a HTML file called home that exists in an app called blog within in a templates directory within a blog directory

This is how my users\model.py file looks like

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to="profile_pics")
    height = models.PositiveIntegerField( null=True, blank=True)
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField( null=True, blank=True)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField( null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width >300:
            output_size = (300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

This is how my users\views.py file looks like

```
def profile(request):
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated successfully!')
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
            p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

        profile_instance = request.user.profile
        context = {
            'u_form': u_form,
            'p_form': p_form,
            'height': profile_instance.height,
            'weight': profile_instance.weight,
            'age': profile_instance.age,
        }
        return render(request,'users/profile.html',context)
```

Just to be sure that my Profile Page works, I checked the admin page, and it shows the data in the profile section.

This is how my blog\views.py file looks like

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    try:
        profile_instance = request.users.profile
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        profile_instance = None
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all(),
        'title': 'Home',
        'profile_instance': profile_instance,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html',context)
```

and this is how blog\home.html looks like

```
{%extends "blog/base.html"%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{%block content%}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div style = "font-size: 25px;">
      <div class="media">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>

            <p>Height: {{ profile_instance.height }}</p>
            <p>Weight: {{ profile_instance.weight }}</p>
            <p>Age: {{ profile_instance.age }}</p>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

{%endblock content%}
```

Here only the user profile, username and email is displayed while the profile height, weight and age is not being displayed.

I excepted all the profile data to be displayed as well but for some reason only the Height: , Weight: and Age: is being displayed. Any help would greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you retrieved profile object wrongly. As profile HAS A user, not User HAS A profile. You should retrieve like this.

```
profile_instance = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
```